# Shading of icons in a Qt combobox possible?

Tags: qt

How can I set a "shading" for QCombobox icons?

I have a QComboxBox with text and icon entries. The icons are nation flags here. The combobox background color is white by default (on Windows). The problem is with the Japan flag, because just a red filled circle is displayed. In other words, I cannot distinguish the white flag color from the combobox background. My workaround is to overrule the combobox base color and set the RGB value to 3*250. Furthermore I don't think it's a good idea to draw a dark border in the original PNG image of the flag.

P.S.: What do you use as workaround for white on white? (I want to know if my workaround is the best solution...)

Comment: I would use flag icons with shadows. Something like this one: http://www.softicons.com/application-icons/lone-shadow-icons-by-vincent-lindqvist/japan-icon or this one: http://www.softicons.com/web-icons/flag-iso-icons-by-icondrawer/japan-icon .

Comment: I don't want cultural misunderstanding due changes to the nation flag, you know